# Express server. Sending Bearer token to header

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http, server

I have a simple form that creates a new user.

[image]

the user types in their credentials,
on the backend, these credentials are validated, saved on database and an auth token is generated.
and finally, as a response, the users name, email and token are returned to the client. So the frontend can manage things.

code:

```
router.post('/user/create', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await sequelize.sync()

        // create new user on database
        const user = await User.create({
            id: shortid.generate(),
            ...req.body
        })

        const token = await user.genAuthToken()

        // create a user token.
        await Tokens.create({
            token,
            userId: user.id
        })

        res.status(201).send({ user, token })
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).send(error)
    }
})
```

well, I created another route. "read user". This route reads the user if it is authenticated.
when i was creating this route and others i used Postman to send a authorization bearer token. If the user is authorized, he can access dashboard and more, otherwise, no.

code:

```
router.get('/user/me', auth, async (req, res) => {
    res.send({ user: req.user, token: req.token })
})
```

authorization middleware:

```
const auth = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const token = req.header('Authorization').replace('Bearer ', '')
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, 'qweasd')

        const userToken = await Tokens.findOne({ where: { userId: decoded._id, token } })
        const userId = userToken.userId
        const user = await User.findOne({ where: { id: userId } })

        if (!user) throw new Error()

        req.user = user
        req.token = token
        next()
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(401).send({ error: 'User not authenticated.' })
    }
}
```

well, from here I want two things:

1. on postman, I had to set the Authorization Bearer token so I can access the dashboard when i create a new account, right? Well, how do i do this outside the postman?
2. on my form, i did set the attributes: action="/user/create" method="POST". when the user pushes the submit button, a json with his name, email and token i what he gets (because he is redirected to /user/create). How can I redirect the user to /dashboard for exmaple?

// EDIT //
my input form html:

```
        <form action="/user/create" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" required>
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email" required>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required>
            <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
            </div>
            <!--upload avatar-->
        </form>
```

Comment: 1. add a request header to the request

Comment: ok, but how exactly ?

router.post('/user/create', async (req, res) => { ( ...code... ) req.setsetHeader = token? or what? }

Comment: Sadly, you cannot add headers with *only* a html form. You have to make an ajax request.

Comment: cannot be done on express nor javascript vanilla?

Comment: It's very difficult to work with bearer tokens when not using a SPA. In fact, I'd say it's reasonably impossible. You won't be able to get the browser to load a page and include the `Authorization` header in the request. If you're not creating a SPA, you'll want session based authentication where the session is maintained by cookies.

Comment: Alright, Phil and ippi  thanks for your answers. Well, as for the second question of mine, i can user res.redirect('/dashboard') instead of res.send() right?